# Appcelerator CLI throwing exception when build

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I'd been using appcelerator CLI for a while and everything is working, until today.

Suddenly when i try to run the following command, an error occur:

```
appc ti build --platform android -T device

C:\Users\User\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\titanium\node_modules\longjohn\dist\longjohn.js:185
    throw e;
          ^
TypeError: Invalid Version: build.0.0
```

I tried to search and found that there are a lot of post regarding the `longjohn.js` throwing `e` as error, but none of them is having the error message `Invalid Version: build.0.0`

I'm running this from *Windows 7*, using *appcelerator 5.0.2*. Targetted *android* platform

Anyone encountered this issue before? Any suggestion or steps to fix this?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

Tried to run `appc info` and got the following error:

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.0.2
Copyright (c) 2014-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

[PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms C:\Users\User\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\appc.js
[PLUGIN-LOAD] 776ms C:\Users\User\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\appc.js
[PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms C:\Users\User\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\arrow\appc.js
ERROR  | titanium exited with exit code 8. re-run with -l trace to get detailed output
```

I tried `appc ti clean` but it doesn't help as well.

**UPDATE with -l trace**

Below is the result i got running `appc info -l trace`:

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.0.2 Copyright (c) 2014-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

__command__ search paths: [   "C:\\Users\\User\\.appcelerator\\install\\5.0.2\\package",   "C:\\Users\\User\\.appcelerator\\install\\5.0.2\\package\\node_modules", "D:\\appcelerator_workspace\\BlackButton\\modules",   "D:\\appcelerator_workspace\\BlackButton\\plugins",   "D:\\appcelerator_workspace\\BlackButton\\node_modules",   "D:\\appcelerator_workspace\\node_modules",   "D:\\node_modules",   "C:\\Users\\User\\.appcelerator\\.npm\\lib\\node_modules" ] [PLUGIN-LOAD] 0ms C:\Users\User\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\appc.js [PLUGIN-LOAD] 718ms C:\Users\User\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\appc.js [PLUGIN-LOAD] 1ms C:\Users\User\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\arrow\appc.js log level set to "trace" executing command "info" set environment to {"registry":"https://software.appcelerator.com","security":"https://security.appcelerator.com","baseurl":"https://platform.appcelerator.com"}

checking credentials for existing session Attempting to load session info from config file check if session is invalidated session expiry 1449554288096 false Arrow Cloud config file: C:\Users\User\.acs found Arrow Cloud login { mid: 'ce9aca6f8de18937ab3063f00c6ea0c8e194c0ef',   publishPort: 443,   publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',   username: 'williamtan89@hotmail.com',   cookie: [ 'connect.sid=s%3A96v7wP3oaYbdV%2BLKu8IdiE3d.cjDf28RzrGOHQbxcd5507u4R STiRnGEO2SvwCG0zNtw; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 15 Dec 2015 05:58:21 GMT; HttpOnly' ],

  defaultEP:    { publishHost: 'https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com',
     publishPort: 443 } } , checking nodeACSEndpoint= https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com Arrow Cloud cookie expiry [ 1450159101000 ] session already loaded in opts.session getCredentials() session: {   "ipaddress": "10.238.179.133",   "username": "williamtan89@hotmail.com",   "password": "<OMITTED>",   "session": "<OMITTED>",   "nonce": "<OMITTED>",   "environment": {
    "name": "production",
    "isProduction": true,
    "acsBaseUrl": "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "acsAuthBaseUrl": "https://secure-identity.cloud.appcelerator.com",
    "nodeACSEndpoint": "https://admin.cloudapp-enterprise.appcelerator.com"   },   "token": "<OMITTED>",   "fingerprint": "ce9aca6f8de18937ab3063f00c6ea0c8e194c0ef",   "fingerprint_description": "Windows Machine ID: b250f9d4-0356-48cd-b9fb-d67ac86e7802",   "org_id": 100032901,   "expiry": 1449554288096 } noPlugins set for command "info" executing command "info" with no plugins "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\User\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\node_modules\titanium\bin\titanium" sdk -o json checking for titanium, result:  { activeSDK: '5.0.2.GA',   defaultInstallLocation: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium',   installLocations:    [ 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium',
     'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Titanium',
     'C:\\ProgramData\\Application Data\\Titanium' ],   installed:    { '5.0.2.GA': 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\5.0.2.GA',
     '5.0.0.v20150920231514': 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\5.0.0.v20150920231514',
     '4.1.1.v20150816214206': 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\4.1.1.v20150816214206',
     '3.2.3.GA': 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\3.2.3.GA' },   sdks:    { '5.0.2.GA':
      { name: '5.0.2.GA',
        manifest: [Object],
        path: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\5.0.2.GA' },
     '5.0.0.v20150920231514':
      { name: '5.0.0.v20150920231514',
        manifest: [Object],
        path: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\5.0.0.v20150920231514' },
     '4.1.1.v20150816214206':
      { name: '4.1.1.v20150816214206',
        manifest: [Object],
        path: 'C:\\ProgramData\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\4.1.1.v20150816214206' },
     '3.2.3.GA':
      { name: '3.2.3.GA',
        manifest: [Object],
        path: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Roaming\\Titanium\\mobilesdk\\win32\\3.2.3.GA' } } } cmd [ '/s',   '/c',   'node',   'C:\\Users\\User\\.appcelerator\\install\\5.0.2\\package\\node_modules\\appc-cli-titanium\\node_modules\\titanium\\bin\\titanium', 'info',   '--color',   '--config',   '{"cli":{"colors":true}}' ] Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 5.0.4, Titanium SDK version 5.0.2.GA Copyright (c) 2012-2015, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.


Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/


8

ERROR  | Error: titanium exited with exit code 8. re-run with -l trace to get detailed output
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\.appcelerator\install\5.0.2\package\lib\commands\info.js:35:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

Comment: could you please add the output of "appc info" and try cleaning your project. If you don't need 5.0.2 try upgrading to 5.1.1 which is the current release.

Comment: updated with appc info error output

Comment: Longhorn is a stack tracer so that's why you find a lot of posts about it. The actual error is what it is about. What do you have as version in tiapp.xml? And could you try updating to the latest CLI (npm i -g appcelerator) and core (appc setup)? Also try "appc info -l trace" for more info on the error.

Comment: Updated with result from `appc info -l trace`. I couldn't use the latest appc as there are some modules in the code that cannot be supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

Please clean your project and build it again.

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on Meta.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311537/1858225)

Comment: Please check whether you the compatible version of the CLI installed or not. You can check the Appcelerator Compatibility Matrix and see which version of the CLI is required to be use 4.0.0.GA SDK.